# Store a typeid().hash_code() into a 16 bits integer

Tags: c++, hash, types, c++11, type-conversion

I would like to know if storing the size_t returned by typeid().hash_code() into a constant size 16 bit unsigned integer can be considered safe or if this will likely produce a collision. What is the safest mode to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: That would very much depend on the size of `size_t`

Comment: Yes, I know, size_t may be 16 bits or even smaller and so it may be fine. But what if size_t is 32 or 64 bits as it usually is? I don't want to introduce impossible-to-spot bugs in a complex code!

Comment: Likely is a relative term - but it should be fairly intuitive that if you are taking an *n*-bit value and compressing it into an *m*-bit value (i.e. if *n > m*) then you will get collisions. The frequency of those collisions depends on many things, all of which are (in this case) for all intents and purposes undefined.

Comment: Safe and producing a collision are not mutually exclusive, as you seem to think. You *must* handle the case that two different types generate the same hash code, just like a hash map does. A hash is a way to place values into buckets, so you only compare values in the same bucket rather than every single one. You can still end up putting two different values in the same bucket (and eventually have to, by the Pigeonhole principle). Pretend your implementation always returns 0 for `hash_code()`.

Comment: @GManNickG Thank you, now I got the concept also from the answer of David.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is safe and also likely produce a collision. There's nothing "unsafe" about collisions. Collisions just reduce performance slightly because if the hashes collide, you have to compare more full values.

A non-matching hash code ensures the values cannot match. A matching hash code only means they might be the same. Hash codes are used to reduce the number of full comparisons needed -- you need only compare values for things whose hash codes match.

Comment: Please, put your answer in the context. 1) detecting a collision means computing all the hashes in advance. 2) solving a collision isn't just simple as comparing full values, but I should somehow assign a different hash to the second type.. and then I cannot use typeid(type2).hash_code() anymore, but I need to wrap this function into a different one which returns the correct modified value. Is this really the way to go?

Comment: @DarioP: 1) No, it doesn't. 2) Yes, it is. (You can use typeid(type2)hash_code() to reduce the number of comparisons needed. Rather than comparing it to every possible typeid, you only need to compare it to the ones with the same hash_code, which should be a tiny fraction of them -- often 1.)

Comment: @DarioP Why do you feel that you *should* you assign a different hash value to `type2` if it's "reduced" hash matches the "reduced" hash of `type1`? It would help if you explained what you are trying to use your "16-bit hash code" for.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: I was building a lookup table to solve a multiple (double) dispatch problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you, now I understood what you meant. I solved the specific problems using an incremental integer associated with each type, however I'm still curious about the original question: how like is it that an hash algorithm produces a collision given n: the number of items, and N: the number of representable items? Does the answer depend on the algorithm?

Comment: @DarioP: It does, but you have to write code to cover that case either way.